# color package and float package collision

Tags: floats, packages, color, incompatibility

I'm writing a document and I wanted to colour some text parts.

In the preamble I call `float` package and many others and it worked properly. until I called `color` package. Then LaTeX return errors at some place in the source code:

```
Missing \endgroup inserted
Missing } inserted
Unbalanced output routine ...
```

By (un)commenting parts of code I've found that `\newfloat{graf}{tbp}{lop}[chapter]` command causes it.

Does anyone have idea why it is working only without `color` package and/or how to define custom floats and be able to use colours?

Thanks for your time and suggestions.

Edit:

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper%,draft%
    ,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,czech]{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}

\newcommand{\dd}{\ensuremath{\mathrm{d}}}

%== Graf environment definition==

\newfloat{graf}{tbp}{lop}[chapter]
\floatname{graf}{Graf}
\newcommand{\listofgraphs}{\listof{graf}{List of Graf}}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\end{document}
```

Comment: 1. Could you please give us a small but complete example showing the problem. 2. Have you already tried replacing the float package by floatrow?

Comment: Lots of people use `color` and `float` together: there must be something else going on here.

Comment: Axel: 1. I've added the code, 2. I'haven't known about that package yet.
Joseph: When I don't define new float both no error occurs. Well, I use only `[H]` option so I should better say 'no error'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok...

Mistake was between chair and screen. As usual.

The problem is not in collision between those packages, problem is caused by the name of my new float - `graf` - and its collision with `color` package. When I used

```
\newfloat{foo}{tbp}{lop}[chapter]
```

No error was throwed.

Axel:

I've tried the `floatrow` package and changed proper commands but same error occurs, so Your advice led me to this conclusion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the course of defining a new floating environment called `graf`, you will (among other things) define the macros `\graf` and `\endgraf`. The latter will cause an error because the `\endgraf` macro is already defined as `\par` by LaTeX (and plain TeX).

Comment: But why it works without problems when `color` package is not loaded?

Comment: @Crowley: I guess that the float definition of `\endgraf` overrides the original definition with `\def`, which won't cause an error by itself. However, any macro or package that will try to use `\endgraf` assuming its original definition will cause unexpected effects and very likely errors.

Comment: Thanks a lot, another thing to avoid as far as possible. :)